# What is happening when using a single integer array to access an item in another array

Tags: javascript

I am a little surprised that this works: http://jsfiddle.net/7yfpc1nL/3/

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b'];
const r = arr[[
  [0]
]];
console.log(r);
```

Does JavaScript coerce [[0]] into 0 here?  What magic is happening here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString#Description

Comment: It'll be converted to a string. So `[[0]].toString()` is `"0"`, and then `arr["0"]` accesses the first element. Fun fact, even normal access uses string conversion, eg: `arr[0]` converts to `arr["0"]` after `(0).toString()`.

Comment: Does it mean when I have ['a', 'b'], it creates {'0': 'a', '1': 'b'} behind the scene?  How does it deal with sorting?

Comment: @techguy2000 An array is just an exotic object with numeric property keys. The enumerable properties of `["a", "b"]` will indeed be `"0"` and `"1"`. It’s not the same as a plain object, because the Array prototype would be missing. You could say `["a", "b"]` is a “superset” of `{"0": "a", "1": "b"}`. `sort` is also on the Array prototype, though I don’t know what you mean by _“how does it deal with sorting”_, or what this has to do with sorting.

Comment: When I think of an array, I think of an ordered structure.  When it's an object like {'0': 'a', '1': 'b'}, it's unordered.  I wonder how javascript array maintains the order when it uses an object underneath the hook.  Maybe I misunderstand the relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when accessing properties of an object with the `[]` operator, JavaScript coerces the argument to a string, and the string form of `[[0]]` is just `0`, so it's a roundabout way to access the zero-th element.

To illustrate:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b']
const idx = String([[0]]) // => "0"
arr[idx] // => "a"
```

We can verify that the string form of the argument is used as such:

```
const obj = {
  toString: function() {
    console.log('OK: called obj.toString()')
    return 1
  }
}
arr[obj] // => "b"
// OK: called obj.toString()
```

Comment: _“JavaScript coerces the argument to a string”_ — unless the expression (which isn’t really an argument) is a symbol.